# Can't reinstall correct version of google play services

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-4, apk, google-play-services

I accidentally installed the wrong version of Google Play Services via an apk, and now it's crashing every 5 minutes and the Google apps don't work.
I tried installing the apk for the right Google Play Services, but it won't install (I think it's because of the signature problems).
The apk install screen just has an "x" saying "app not installed."
I can't uninstall or disable the old/wrong play services.

Any solutions?

Thanks.

---

Maybe helpful information:

Nexus 4, CM 12.1

The correct version is -436, right?

Comment: Try downloading the latest gapps from [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/gapps-google-apps-minimal-edition-t2943330) and flash this from recovery. Google play services will automatically update in the background. Don't install it manually.
Main thread: [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/gapps-consolidated-gapps-thread-t3064693)

Comment: I keep on getting an error message when flashing gapps:
"E: footer is wrong 
E: signature verification failed 
Installation aborted."

Comment: You might need to turn off signature verification in recovery. Refer here : https://starburstregional.wordpress.com/starburst-rom-home/resources/how-to-turn-off-signature-verification/. If even that is not working, install Philz or TWRP recovery and try flashing again.

Comment: I turned off signature verification in cwm and the gapps flashed fine, but when I rebooted, the old Google Play Services was still there.

Comment: Did you clear cache and dalvik cache after flashing?

Comment: Purge the Play Services along with the framework completely off the device. Use [TitaniumBackup](http://www.titaniumtrack.com/kb/titanium-backup-kb) or a system apps remover tool to do the job. Thereafter, flash the GAPPS as @uberz91 said.

Comment: I uninstalled play services with TitaniumBackup but flashing gapps didn't install Google Play services, so I installed it with the correct apk. I'm pretty sure it works now, but Android Keyboard (AOSP) keeps crashing. Maybe it's related? Or maybe it has to do with the build of CM12.1 that I installed (20150710).